# git: view source code of specific commit in parallel

Tags: git, commit, difftool

I am working on source code and want to review the code of a previous commit. Usually I would do this with `git difftool --dir-diff` and meld as the difftool. However, when I want to look at a farther back commit, or a commit that was prior to a refactor, meld makes it hard to read because the code is altered too much.

The other solution I can think of is to `git stash` the changes, checkout the other commit and view the code. But then I can't view my current code and it also takes quite long.

I am looking for (maybe) a tool, that opens the source code of a previous commit for me to view parallel to the current code. Basically like the `dirdiff` solution without the diff part. I am using the git cli. Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Consider using `git worktree add` to add a separate work-tree with a detached HEAD that is looking at the commit you care about. Since it's a separate work-tree, it does not affect what you're working on; since it's a complete checkout, all your source-examination tools should work fine on it.

Comment: @torek: this is awesome! I never heard of this feature. Please post this comment as an answer, then I will accept it. BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a situation like this, I prefer to use `git worktree add`.  This creates a separate `git checkout` (or `git switch` in Git 2.23 or later), in a separate work-tree that has its own private index / staging-area and other private items, so that the separate work-tree does not interfere with your ongoing work in your main work-tree.

The independent work-tree can be used as much as you like, or left alone as much as you like.  It is a full checkout.  The main constraint on an added work-tree is that it must be on a *different* branch from any existing work-tree (including other added work-trees), but if you intend to look at one specific commit, you can just use the "detached HEAD" mode in the added work-tree to view the one specific commit.  All detached-HEAD added work-trees are by definition not on any branch at all and therefore are OK.

There are two minor caveats—things to be aware of—when using `git worktree`:

- It was first added in Git 2.5, so if your Git is older than that, you don't have it.
- It had a pretty gnarly bug in it until Git 2.15.  This bug only affects an addded work-tree where you make *changes* to it and then let them sit around for two weeks or more, so if all you are doing is *inspecting* an old commit, it won't bite you at all.  If you start making heavy use of `git worktree add`, though, I recommend being sure your Git version is at least 2.15.